# AngularJS: Select with ng-options- how to pass value as integer?

Tags: angularjs, select, ng-options

I am having an issue with my select form. When I select any option, the value that is being passed is of a string type, instead of number type. Here is my object that I use for ng-repeat:

```
$scope.apples ={
         0:'Apple0',
         1:'Apple1',
         2:'Apple2',
         3:'Apple3'
};
```

And here is my select, which passes string, instead of number:

```
 <select ng-model="test" ng-options="key as value for (key,value) in apples"></select>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time you're iterating on object fields, IMO, there is a design problem. Use an array:

```
$scope.apples = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Apple0'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Apple1'
  },
  ...
];
```

and in the view:

```
ng-options="apple.id as apple.name for apple in apples"
```

Comment: That works. I know it is off topic, but could you explain me what are the benefits of this design over the original one?

Comment: The order is predictible, whereas it's not when using an object. And you can sort the array (by ID or, more realistically, by name): `apple.id as apple.name for apple in apples | orderBy:'name'`.

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Very simple approach is to actually cast string to number (note, `+` operator):

```
ng-options="+key as value for (key,value) in apples"
```

It's also possible to use array as data structure:

```
$scope.apples = [
    'Apple0',
    'Apple1',
    'Apple2',
    'Apple3'
];
```

and then

```
ng-options="apples.indexOf(apple) as apple for apple in apples"
```